# Python:extract text after </span> before <br/>

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Here is the html file I am going to handle:

```
<span class="pl">Countries:</span> USA <br/>
<span class="pl">Language:</span> English <br/>
```

And here is my python code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

record=[]
soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
spans=soup.find_all('span')
for span in spans:
   record.append(span.text)
```

What I finally got is:

```
Countries: Language:
```

The result miss some important information :"USA" and "English"
How can I get the text?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`.next_sibling`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) notation:

```
soup.find("span", text="Countries:").next_sibling
soup.find("span", text="Language:").next_sibling
```