# Beautifulsoup - get text not between specific tags (after </span> but before <br>)?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've looked around and found solutions that have worked or suppose to work for this exact question, but it will not work for this situation. Anyone have a reason why it would work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122074/pythonextract-text-after-span-before-br), and not here? Or just simply show what I'm doing wrong, and I can work out the difference.

Keep in mind, I'm just giving a snippet of the html, it contains much more with the same `span` and `class='boldText'`. I'm specifically wanting the tag with `Status:` as its text, then the next text/content following that.

```
import bs4 

html1 = '''<span class="boldText"><b>Date:</b>  </span>12/04/2018<br/>
<span class="boldText"><b>Name:</b>  </span>Aaron Rodgers<br/>
<span class="boldText"><b>Status:</b>  </span>Questionable<br/><br/>
<br/>
<br/><br/><br/>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html1,'html.parser') 
status = soup.find(text='Status:').next_sibling
```

I'm just trying to get the text: `'Questionable'`

so looking for output:

```
>>> print (status)
>>> Questionable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `b` tag has no siblings. It's easier to see when formatted like this:

```
<span class="boldText">
    <b>Status:</b>
</span>
Questionable
<br/>
```

See how the `b` is the only child of the `span`? The string "Questionable" is actually a sibling of the parent `span`, so you need to navigate to it as follows:

```
print(soup.find('b', string='Status:').parent.next_sibling)
# => 'Questionable'
```

Comment: ahhh. yes. I see now. completely makes sense. Thanks for the explanation. that really helps.